# Use Farbtastic with classes instead of id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, textinput, color-picker

I've got:

```
<input type="text" id="color1" value="<?php echo get_option('color1'); ?>" name="color_picker_color1" /><div class="farbtastic_color_picker"></div>
<input type="text" id="color2" value="<?php echo get_option('color2'); ?>" name="color_picker_color2" /><div class="farbtastic_color_picker"></div>
```

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.farbtastic_color_picker').hide();
    jQuery('.farbtastic_color_picker').farbtastic("#color1");
    jQuery("#color1").click(function(){jQuery('.farbtastic_color_picker').slideToggle()});
</script>
```

What do I need to change in the script section, so I don't have to duplicate the code? Now it's only for the text iput with #color1. I'd like to use the code on multiple #'s (color1, color2, color3 etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
jQuery('input[name^="color_picker_color"]')
```

Comment: can you show me how to use this in

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.farbtastic_color_picker').hide();
    jQuery('.farbtastic_color_picker').farbtastic("#color1");
    jQuery("#color1").click(function(){jQuery('.farbtastic_color_picker').slideToggle()});
</script>

Comment: Of course:  replace `jQuery("#color1")` with `jQuery('input[name^="color_picker_color"]')`